# Why does my Math.random function always return the same value?

Tags: javascript

I am making a game of rock, paper, scissors where the computer makes a random choice against the player. I created a function that will randomly select a number (0,1, or 2), then based off the number return a value of rock, paper, or scissors. I am only ever able to get 'paper' as a result.

```
function getComputerChoice() {
  Math.floor(Math.random() * 3);
  if (0) {
    return 'rock';
  }
  else if (1) {
    return 'paper';
  }
  else if (2) {
    return 'scissors';
  }
}
console.log(getComputerChoice());


Expected: 0, 1, or 2
Actual result: always 1
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're doing `Math.floor(Math.random() * 3)` but then throwing away the result. Then in your `if` statement, you're testing whether the number `0` is true (which it isn't), and then whether the number `1` is true (which it is), and thus always returning paper. To fix it, you need to save your random number to a variable, and then compare the variable to the possible numbers in the `if` statements.

Answer (score 0):

You need to capture and then evaluate the result of `Math.floor(Math.random() * 3);` Like this:

```js
function getComputerChoice() {
  let random_pick = Math.floor(Math.random() * 3);
  if (random_pick == 0) {
    return 'rock';
  }
  else if (random_pick == 1) {
    return 'paper';
  }
  else {
    return 'scissors';
  }
}
console.log(getComputerChoice());
```